# Why do pre-defined variables not behave as expected in Cypress?

Tags: angular, testing, cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I'm getting wacky results when pre-defining element variables and using them afterwards in Cypress 10 w/ Cucumber. Consider this login test:

```js
Given("I'm logged in as Default user", () => {        

    cy.visit('/');

    let usernameField = cy.get('#myUsernameInputField');
    let passwordField = cy.get('#myPasswordInputField');
    let signInButton = cy.get('#mySignInButton');
  
    usernameField.clear();

    usernameField.type('myUsername@gmail.com');
   
    passwordField.type('myPassword');
  
    signInButton.click();

});
```

This results in both the username and password being typed into the passwordField, and the signInButton never being clicked. Only when I rearrange the variables in a more chronological order does this test behave as expected:

```js
Given("I'm logged in as Default user", () => {

    cy.visit('/');

    let usernameField = cy.get('#myUsernameInputField');
    usernameField.clear();
    usernameField.type('myUsername@gmail.com');

    let password = cy.get('#myPasswordInputField');
    password.type('myPassword');
  
    let signInButton = cy.get('#mySignInButton');
    signInButton.click();

});
```

I planned to eventually move these variables into a page object file. But here in the test, they don't behave as expected when I pre-define them and try to use them later. Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you shouldn't hold references to query results in plain javascript variables.

The reason is, Cypress runs on a queue system and the queue has only one "subject" at any time.

You should think of the queue as a separate thread or execution process that runs asynchronously to the test execution, so it's possible that the variables in the thread are getting out of sync with the queue subject.

---

The conventional way to do this is to use the query results immediately like

```js
cy.get('#myUsernameInputField').type('myUsername@gmail.com');
```

then move on to the next query (password).

If for some reason you do need a reference to the query result, Cypress has an `alias` mechanism to handle it

```js
cy.get('#myUsernameInputField').as('username)

...
// later in the test

cy.get('@username').type('myUsername@gmail.com');
```

Comment: Thanks Fody. FYI, another workaround I found was setting the variable to a function, and only calling the function when needed (which would then call cy.get(). This worked at first, but over multiple tests (logging in and out between) resulted in a race condition that can happen when you attempt actions on the same elements later. The dreaded, and very widespread "this element is detached from the DOM" error. This is objectively a poor developer experience, so Cypress team is working on a fix (they are halfway finished). See https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/7306

Comment: Interesting will have to take a look. The alias code already checks for detached elements and re-runs the original query if subject is found to be detached (using `Cypress.dom.isAttached($el)`). Necessary since an alias can be used after the DOM has changed (and invalidated the original query). Seems to have limitations - not all queries can be re-run. The examples you have (simple get by id) should be ok to re-query.

Comment: Cypress's queue system is the most unnecessarily complex paradigm in the whole of E2E testing.

Comment: Yes, it's brilliant at handling complex testing scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign or work with the return values of any Cypress command. Commands are enqueued and run asynchronously.

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases